# Re module and positive look behind of variable width

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am new to programming and Python, so I apologize if this is an obvious question. I tried looking at similar questions on this website, but the solutions seem to be outside of my reach.

**Problem:** Consider the following text:

12/19 Paul 1/20

1/20 Jacob 10/2

Using the module re, extract the names from the above. In other words, your output should be:

['Paul', 'Jacob']

First, I tried using positive look arounds. I tried:

```
import re

name_regex=re.compile(r'''(
(?<=\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\s)      #looks for one or two digits followed by a forward slash followed by one or two digits, followed by a space
.*?                        #looks for anything besides the newline in a non-greedy manner (is the non-greedy part necessary? I am not sure...)
(?=\s\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})  #looks for a space followed by one or two digits followed by a forward slash followed by one or two digits
)''', re.VERBOSE)

text=str("12/19 Paul 1/20\n1/20 Jacob 10/2")
print(name_regex.findall(text))
```

However, the above yields the error:

```
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

From reading similar questions, I believe that this means that look arounds cannot have variable length (i.e., they cannot look for "1 or 2 digits").

However, how can I fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Especially the help suited for nearly a complete beginner like me!

PS. Ultimately, the list of names surrounded by dates can be very long. The dates can have one or two digits that are separated by a slash. I just wanted to give a minimal working example.

Thank you!

Comment: @Emma Thanks, that nearly worked! I got the following output: ['Paul', '1/20 Jacob'].  So almost what I wanted. Any idea how to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match at least a single non whitespace char between the digit patterns, you might use

```
(?<=\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\s)\S.*?(?=\s\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})
```

This part `\S.*?` will match a non whitespace char followed by any char except a newline non greedy so it will match until asserting the first occurrence of `(?=\s\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})`

[Python demo](https://rextester.com/WZPE10807)

**Note** that if you would use `.*?` then match would also return an empty entry `['Paul', '', 'Jacob']` , see [this example](https://rextester.com/KYAH13923).

---

You could also use a capturing group instead of lookarounds:

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\s(\S.*?)\s\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2hJPv/1)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks

Comment: @Pawel Is there any particular reason to use the lookarounds?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Alexander, I am not sure. I am learning Python on my own, so that was the first thing that I thought of. My thought process was the following: I want to capture the name without the dates around it. So I want my computer to look for the pattern: "date name date" and capture only the name. A few google searches led me to reading about lookarounds. However, I am not sure if that is the best or the most efficient method of doing such searches.

Comment: @Pawel It seems fine, although I would have used the capturing group, as suggested by The Fourth bird.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks, I somehow did not think about capturing the name with the capturing group. The capturing group solution seems clear to me now, but I have no idea why I did not come up with it myself. Oh well. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @Pawel If you haven’t heard of it before, I recommend the website https://regex101.com/. I find it invaluable for anything involving RegEx.